# Где лучше хранить данные для дальнейшего поиска по ним?

Tags: android, java, база-данных

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста , в android приложении необходимо хранить данные и осуществлять по ним поиск. К примеру если есть запись "День рождения" ,пользователь введет слово "День" и выдача должна показать эту запись целиком.

Где необходимо хранить данные что бы осуществлять такой поиск с наименьшими проблемами?В данный момент храню в SharedPreferences и понимаю что если я хочу так искать, то нужно будет очень сильно запариться =(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос содержится в тегах, которые вы же и поставили к нему. :)

> database

В SQLite есть поиск по точному и частичному (like) совпадению, а так же full-text search. Таким образом, SQLite полностью покрывает вашу задачу своей функциональностью. Ну а остальное зависит уже от вас, как реализуете.